# Strange IE issue: Dropdown menu hides behind an absolute positioned image, only in some servers

Tags: css, internet-explorer

This is strange. I had spent some time to try figuring it but no luck.

So please visit using IE any version : http://sumsy.com/temp/ie-issue/
hover over Menu1 on the top, you will see submenu.

Does the submenu go behind the image for you, in IE?

1) using my web host: http://sumsy.com/temp/ie-issue/
The sub-menu is just fine. show before the image.

2) using my localhost, inside company network. the path is something like: http://mypc-name/...
the sub-menu goes behind the image.

3) using localhost, the path is something like C://...
The sub-menu is just fine. show before the image.

It's just the same code and same files. No sure why the sub-menu is behaving differently in my localhost within company network.

Any idea? and, is the sub-menu working for you?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Please fix your html page, as it points to an unreachable vand03052 host and can't be seen properly...

Comment: sorry about that. its fixed now. please take a look.

Comment: Did my answer solve your issue? If so, please kindly mark it as the answer for your question. Thanks!

Comment: actaully, i needed to add z-index: 10000 to the parent div #intranetbar. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a z-index issue here. Please try to increase its value for the `#navIntranet li ul` CSS rule as follows:

```
z-index: 10000;
```